# Indexeddb - Prevent multiple tabs/windows accessing item at the same time

Tags: indexeddb

Within my web application I have queue of items in indexeddb which need to be processed in order then removed from the queue, the queue is currently being processed on a timer, each item can take several seconds to process.

How can I prevent multiple tabs processing the queue at the same time?

I have considered setting a status on the item to indicate it is being processed but in the tab/window is closed then the item will get stuck at that status and block the queue.

How can I ensure on one tab / window can process the queue in indexeddb at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If processing is taking several seconds, it sounds like that's involving async work outside of IndexedDB itself (e.g. some network requests, UI updates, etc). So simply using an IDB transaction is not feasible.

In that case, take a look at the Web Locks API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Locks_API which is designed for exactly this sort of cross-tab coordination, at a higher level than a database transaction. Each tab can try and grab the lock when it needs to do work; if another tab has the lock the callback won't be executed. The tab that has the lock holds it until async operations are completed.

The underlying operation (database, network, etc) aren't automatically integrated with the locking, so you'll need to rig up promise resolutions that happen at the right time, e.g. wrapping the IDB work in promises. But the Web Locks API should help with the overall coordination, and it's available in all browsers these days.

Comment: Thanks i did come across these but was a bit concerned about the "experimental" status. However will try them, thanks